# How can I get compare button in header section with the same functionality as of cart button

Tags: layout, magento-2.1.3, compare

I'm an IT student and new in magento.

I was wondering, how can I create compare button as on that link http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/

I found sidebar.phtml file under vendor/magento/module-catalog/..../compare/
but I cannot find any code which would be responsible for creating that button with whole functionality.

Please help. I was looking for any answer in google but mostly there are topic about 'how to disable compare button/features etc' and nobody is asking how to add it.

I would appreciate for any help, advices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 'Compare' button then the details are as under:

First go to page.xml and insert

<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>

in header block.

Now call getChildHtml('catalog.compare.sidebar'); ?> in header.phtml

Change the layout html in file sidebar.phtml path (\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\compare\sidebar.phtml)

Clear admin cache if it is enabled & refresh the page.